# Laravel session has value

Tags: laravel, session

```
if(! session()->exists('disease', $val)){
    $request->session()->push('disease', $val);
}
```

I want to add a value (text) for disease only if it is not in array. How to archive this in Laravel 8? I can assign the session array to a var and do a php array_unique. But is there a beautiful way in Laravel?

Thank you all.

Comment: so `if (! in_array($val, session()->get('disease', []))) { session()->push('disease', $val); }` ?

Comment: yes, this works. Looking for Laravel style!

Answer (score 1):

`->exists()` only takes a single argument, `$key`:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Session/Session.php#L64.

If you want to check that `'disease'` is in the session and equals `$val`, then you can do:

```php
if (session()->get('disease', null) !== $val) {
  session()->push('disease', $val);
}
```

If `'disease'` in the session is present and already equal to `$val`, then nothing will happen. Otherwise, it will add it to the session.

Edit: Since `'disease'` is an array, not a single value, you'll need to adjust your code a bit:

```php
$diseases = session()->get('disease', []);
if (!in_array($val, $diseases)) {
  $diseases[] = $val;
  session()->put('disease', $diseases);
}
```

You should be able to use `->push()` as suggested in the comments, and as evidenced by your current `'disease'` array, but the same idea applies; only append to the array if it's not already there.

Comment: ->exists() only takes a single argument, $key: I saw that @ Laravel doc. but it did not through an error!

Comment: it is still pushing
. . . [disease] => Array ( [0] => sadwaking [1] => sadwaking [2] => sadwaking ) )

Comment: Ah, ok, so `'disease'` is an array, not a single value. Gotcha. I'll adjust my answer. And yeah, adding an extra argument to `->exists()` doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't do anything 

Comment: push will create an array. put will overwrite existing values. isn't it so?

Comment: So use that instead. The main issue is you're not checking for `!in_array(...)`, and you can have multiple of the same value in an array. Does my answer help at all? Or no?

Comment: You would have the same outcome doing `->push('disease', $val)` as your would `->put('disease', $diseases)` in my answer; you can use either syntax approach, but the result would be the same.